# Errors while converting to Decimal Format

Tags: java, android, mysql, coordinates, decimalformat

Hey guys i'm working with gps locations, so i am getting coordinates, what i need now is to pass those coordinates to my web service and store it to my database. But i am having trouble storing it in a proper way, i think the data that i am getting is too big for the database, that's why i am trying to convert the coordinates to decimal format. I have some errors when i put the DecimaFormat method in my codes, can you help me guys.

These are the errors:

```
03-13 22:03:16.733: E/WindowManager(1018): Activity com.example.projectthesis.Mapping2 has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41319870 that was originally added here
03-13 22:03:16.733: E/WindowManager(1018): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.projectthesis.Mapping2 has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41319870 that was originally added here
03-13 22:03:16.733: E/WindowManager(1018):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:344)
03-13 22:03:16.733: E/WindowManager(1018):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:267)
03-13 22:03:16.733: E/WindowManager(1018):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:215)
03-13 22:03:16.733: E/WindowManager(1018):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:140)
03-13 22:03:16.733: E/WindowManager(1018):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:537)
03-13 22:03:16.733: E/WindowManager(1018):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:278)
03-13 22:03:16.733: E/WindowManager(1018):  at com.example.projectthesis.Mapping2$phpconnect.onPreExecute(Mapping2.java:190)
03-13 22:03:16.733: E/WindowManager(1018):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:561)
03-13 22:03:16.733: E/WindowManager(1018):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:511)
03-13 22:03:16.733: E/WindowManager(1018):  at com.example.projectthesis.Mapping2$GPSLocationListener.onLocationChanged(Mapping2.java:124)
03-13 22:03:16.733: E/WindowManager(1018):  at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(LocationManager.java:234)
03-13 22:03:16.733: E/WindowManager(1018):  at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.access$000(LocationManager.java:167)
03-13 22:03:16.733: E/WindowManager(1018):  at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.handleMessage(LocationManager.java:183)
03-13 22:03:16.733: E/WindowManager(1018):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-13 22:03:16.733: E/WindowManager(1018):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-13 22:03:16.733: E/WindowManager(1018):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
03-13 22:03:16.733: E/WindowManager(1018):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-13 22:03:16.733: E/WindowManager(1018):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-13 22:03:16.733: E/WindowManager(1018):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-13 22:03:16.733: E/WindowManager(1018):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-13 22:03:16.733: E/WindowManager(1018):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and these are my codes(specifically on the passing process and DecimalFormat method):

```
class phpconnect extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Mapping2.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Logging in..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            String strLatitude = Long.toString(ILatitude);
            String strLongitude = Long.toString(ILongitude);

            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###.00000");
            String frmLat = df.format(strLatitude);
            String frmLong = df.format(strLongitude);
            // Building parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("latitude", frmLat));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("longitude", frmLong));
            // getting JSON Object
            // Note that create product url accepts POST method
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                    "POST", params);
            // check log cat fro response
            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully updated
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            Mapping2.class);

                    startActivity(i);
                    // closing this screen
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // failed to create product
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: That error doesn't look related to database calls at all.

Comment: yeah yeah, i think it's because on the Decimal format, i don't know how to deal with it. Before i put that code, it's working, but the problem is the coordinates that i store in my database, it became 999.99999 =, just like that.

Answer (score 1):

What I find strange in your code is that ILatitude and ILongitude are apparently of the `Long` type.
Latitude and longitude are better represented as `double` values. I think `DecimalFormat` is not really needed here and that a simple `String.valueOf(ILatitude);` should suffice, considering you make ILatitude a double.

Comment: Yes, before, it was in double format i just tried long so that i can see if that works. Thank you for answering. But are you recommending me to use that String.valueOf(ILatitude); ?

Comment: Well yes, unless you need to format your double in a specific way. Padding it with zeroes or showing only three decimals for example.

Answer (score 0):

You should be passing a `long` or a `double` to the `format` method.  When you pass a `String` object, the method is throwing a `IllegalArgumentException` causing your `doInBackground` method to end prematurely.  Consequently, the dialog that you create in `onPreExecute` is not getting dismissed and is leaked.